# How do you use the Gettext library with Codeigniter for i18n?

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, gettext

I’m finally developing my first multilingual site which came from an old no-CI site which used Gettext cause there’s a lot of text and not just actions. I’m really struggling to make the gettext library to work with CI, having read the [WIKI](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category%3aInternationalization%3a%3aGettext/) (first option) but I lacks information and examples.

1. Is there someone here who has used
   the gettext library succesfully?
2. Can you post some examples of controller
   and views?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend NOT using CI's language libraries for this.  Use Poedit or another `gettext()`/`ngettext()` replacement program.

Trust me--you'll want all your externalized strings in a compiled format.  Doing this from scratch is far more work than it's worth.

Comment: That's not what he asked for

Comment: If you have a better answer, why not give it?